# Function $f$ such that $f$ is non-periodic but $f(f(x))$ is?

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

Is there a "nice" example of a function $f$ such that $f(x)$ is non-periodic but the composition $f(f(x))$ is? By nice I mean that preferably it will be defined entirely on the domain $R$ and be continuous/differentiable with the composition having non-zero period.

For example the function $f(x>0)=-x, f(x \leq 0) = 0$ is not nice.

Comment: How does the example function have a periodic composition?

Comment: @Aniket for negative x we have $f(f(x))=f(0)=0$, for positive $f(f(x))=f(-x)=0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple example: $f(x)=\sin|x|$.

Comment: Is it possible to smooth out the function at $x=0$ to get an everywhere differentiable one?

Comment: Does $\sin^3|x|$ work?

Comment: Yes. Following Michael's comment you can take $f(x)=\sin^{2k+1}|x|$, $k\in\mathbb N$, which is of class $C^{2k}$. It should be obvious now how to construct a $C^\infty$ example.

Comment: That is indeed "nice" :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a(x)$ be the sum of the binary digits of $\lfloor\,|x|\,\rfloor$.  I think that is not periodic.
$$f(x)=\sin^2(\pi x)(-1)^{a(x)}$$

Comment: Sorry, now it should be.

Answer (score 1):

One smooth function that works is
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases}
-\exp[-1/x] & x>0 \\
0 & x \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$
However, this doesn't give us a non-zero period.